# Promises and async/await in an infinite loop in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying a TCP/IP socket communication between my nodeJS server to an external legacy JAVA application in a request/response mode where nodeJS is a socket client and external application is socket server. I am using promises to wait for the response from server after making a request from my NodeJS client in a periodic cycle in an infinite loop.

This works fine for some time but gives warning after some time saying number of maximum listeners exceeded in nodeJS. I can suppress this warning by increasing max number of listeners in nodeJS, but is it right to do so? I think this will eventually lead to memory leaks. I guess this is happening because each promise call creates an event listener which is never removed and when I call promise function in a loop this will keep on growing the number of listeners!

So my question is:

1. Is there a way to remove listener created by a promise call after it has been called once?
2. Is it safe to ignore the warning and let the execution proceed even if its in a never ending loop?
3. Will replacing promise with async/await help? I guess it may not as this also will add a new listener for each await call.
4. Do you have any suggestions or solutions? There are no synchronous socket calls in nodeJS as far as I know.

Comment: [Related](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues?q=is%3Aissue+Possible+EventEmitter+memory+leak+detected+is%3Aclosed)

Comment: Is it a normal Node `EventEmitter` you're listening to? If so, it has a `once()` method that will automatically unregister the listener after a single event.

Comment: 1) yes, you need to remove the callback if the event emitter keeps emitting events 2) no, you should not amass listeners 3) you cannot replace promises with async/await. You can only replace promise `then` syntax with promise await syntax.

Comment: Please post your code (how you are listening to the events, and how you are using the promises in a loop) so that we can advise on what to change

Comment: To directly answer your question, you may need to `cache` a Promise once created, and use it later whenever available rather then creating a new one. I should suggest you get better understanding of NodeJS events, because most of official NodeJS APIs are event driven, you should try using callbacks rather then promise, and avoid using infinite loop since it is preferred in C / JAVA and costs as much CPU load as it can.

Comment: you should certainly not ignore the warnings. As you suspect, they are telling you that your program is not setting event handlers properly and it will eventually fail. You should post your code if you want any of the other questions answered though, since it's impossible to know how you're setting listeners without seeing your code.